# Most efficient way to check array based on other array limitation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following set of arrays and I want to check which array meet the condition by the following arrays `must_inculde, optional_include, must_not_include`

- Each array must include the the letters in `must_inculde`.
- The array should not have any of the `must_not_include`.
- The values in `optional_include` can be in addition on `must_inculde` but they are not must.

```
    my_arr = [['a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'e'],
              ['a', 'e'],
              ['a', 'c', 'f'],
              ['a', 'c', 'b'],
              ['a', 'b', 'd'],
              ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']]
    
    must_inculde = ['a', 'b']
    optional_include = ['c', 'd']
    must_not_include = ['f']
```

Comment: Would there be any functional difference if the optional_include array were omitted entirely?

Comment: Im not sure that I understand you, do you mean if optional_include was not there at all?

Comment: Ok, I got you, sorry for the delay. When I think about it optional_include is indeed not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optionals are not interesting as an array can never fail because of this piece of information: if it does not have all those elements it's OK, if it does, it's also OK.

So you just need to check for the includes and not-includes, and for that you can use `every` and `includes` array methods:

```js
let my_arr = [['a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'e'],
              ['a', 'e'],
              ['a', 'c', 'f'],
              ['a', 'c', 'b'],
              ['a', 'b', 'd'],
              ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']]
    
let must_include = ['a', 'b']
let optional_include = ['c', 'd']
let must_not_include = ['f']

let result = my_arr.filter(arr => 
        must_include.every(val => arr.includes(val))
     && must_not_include.every(val => !arr.includes(val))
); 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This could have n log n time complexity if must_include and must_not_include were converted to Sets first. Then, instead of using every() , which performs a linear search on every call, you could use Set.prototype.has(), which presumably has O(log n) complexity, if not O(1)

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fja32w80/. It's certainly not as elegant as trincot's solution, but it's more efficient as the arrays grow in size

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a mirror array with `true` or `false` for the "statements":

```js
var my_arr = [['a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'e'],
              ['a', 'e'],
              ['a', 'c', 'f'],
              ['a', 'c', 'b'],
              ['a', 'b', 'd'],
              ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']];
var must_inculde = ['a', 'b'];
var optional_include = ['c', 'd'];
var must_not_include = ['f'];

var mirror=my_arr.map(item=>({
  must_inculde:must_inculde.reduce((acc,element)=>{acc=acc&&item.includes(element);return acc;},true),
  optional_include:item.some(element=>optional_include.includes(element)),
  must_not_include:!item.some(element=>must_not_include.includes(element))
}));

console.log(mirror);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```